# Can someone explain to me the space complexity of this leetcode solution I wrote?

Tags: javascript, space-complexity

I feel like it's not even that important in this scenario but I want to have a strong fundamental understanding of it.

When using functions such as filter or map to manipulate strings and similar data does that increase the space complexity to o(N)?

And in the case of the solution below would the space complexity be O(1)?

And lastly are there any likely instances where a space complexity of O(N^2) would occur?

```js
// BACKSPACE COMPARE  (DATA-STRUCTURE STRING/ARRAY)

/*
Given two strings S and T, return if they equal when both are typed out.
ANy '#' that appears in the string counts as a backspace
*/

const backspaceCompare = (s, t) => {
    /*
    turn strings into an array
    see if the array has an '#'
    if it does, filter out '#' and the number before it
    compare the two arrays after and see if they're equal
    */

    // this filters out a '#' and deletes the previous item each time it's called
    const filteringFunc = (arr, index1, index2) => {
            const arrFiltered = arr.filter((val, index) => {
               return index !== index1 && index !== index2;
            });
            return arrFiltered;  
    };
    
    // change the strings to arrAYS because filter function only works on arrays
    let sArr = s.split('');
    let tArr = t.split('');

    // while there's a '#' this function will call the filter function and filter out each instance of '#' as well as its previous index
    const eradicateHash = (arr) => {
        while(arr.includes('#')){
            const removeThis = arr.indexOf('#');
            const andThis = removeThis - 1;
            arr = filteringFunc(arr, removeThis, andThis);
        };
        return arr;
    };
    // calling the function on the arrays
    sArr = eradicateHash(sArr);
    tArr = eradicateHash(tArr);
    
    // after arrays have been filtered it has to be changed to a stirng because arrays by themselves cannot be compared to other arrays
    sArr = sArr.toString();
    tArr = tArr.toString();

    // returning via the ternary operator
    return tArr === sArr ? true : false;
};
```

Comment: Why do you think it's O(1)?

Comment: The levenshtein distance would be an example for an algorithm with O(n * m) space complexity

Comment: I think it might be O(1) because the functions don't create any additional variables. They just reset the value to something less. I'm not too sure though

Comment: So `backspaceCompare("1", "2")` will occuy the same memory as `backspaceCompare("1....a few million digits", "2 .... a few million digits")` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have here (and which you'll have in any other real world example):

- what is *space*? Do you count the memory, files on the disk, registers? Modern computers are inherently complex and you won't find a clear definition on what space actually is.
- what is *input*? If you take an array as argument to our function, then push a bazillion of items to it, is your algorithm still O(1) as it only increases the input? If no, how is your algorithm different? What about references, does passing in a reference (which has a fixed size) always have n = 1 or do you take the size the array references into as n?

Given these two unanswerable questions, we can basically say your algorithm has a space complexity of O(1), o(n) or anything else, as you can always argue somehow whether that is right or wrong, this is not useful at all.

Instead let's take a step back and have a look at a concrete computational resource as defined in theoretical computer science, [DSPACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSPACE). DSPACE describes the numbers of cells on the work tape in relation to the input tape of a deterministic turing machine². As other space resources are rather theoretical (e.g. NSPACE, the space a non deterministic turing machine would take), one can say that DSPACE *is* space complexity for all real world uses. Now if we look at a turing machine, we avoid the problems above, because *space* is clearly defined (each cell holds one character of the alphabet, so the length of the tape is an integer), and *input* is clearly defined as we separated the *input tape* from the *working tape*. The length of the input tape we call n, and we search the size of the working tape.

Now to show that your algorithm is in DSPACE(O(n)) or DSPACE(O(1)) one would have to reformulate your program as a turing machine. This is actually a fun exercise, though we can actually simplify this step by taking an observation you made: "They just reset the value to something less", or in other words, the algorithm takes two strings of length m and l, and *modifies* them till all # are removed. Then it compares them. Now given that we can't actually modify the input tape (it is read-only), in our Turing machine, as a first step we would have to copy all symbols from the input tape to the working tape. We might be able to build the machine in such a way that the # gets removed while copying, however there could still be an input without # in it, and then we copy the whole input into the working tape. That means that the working tape must be as large as the input, or in other words:

```
L ∈ DSPACE(n) = DSPACE(O(n))
```

Wether *O(n)* is now actually useful as an answer to your question is very debatable, as we aren't running on turing machines.

Now to your other questions:

> When using functions such as filter or map to manipulate strings and similar data does that increase the space complexity to o(N)?

Yes. In a Turing machine, both filter and map would have to copy the input tape into the working tape.

> And lastly are there any likely instances where a space complexity of O(N^2) would occur?

A cell in the working tape which doesn't get visited by the turing machine is useless, therefore at a minimum the turing machine will at least do as many steps as it has cells. Thus time complexity is always worse than space complexity. Therefore you can find a lot of algorithms in DTIME(O(n²)) (think of e.g. bubblesort) that are also in DSPACE(O(n)). Therefore to find an algorithm that is in DSPACE(O(n²)) you'd have to look at algorithms whose time complexity is way worse, making them less useful for real world applications. So yes, it is very unlikely you'll meet an algorithm in DSPACE(O(n²))

---

² To get a feeling for Turing machines, play with this [Google Doodle](https://www.google.com/doodles/alan-turings-100th-birthday)